# How to keep an `screen` going with emacs? If I kill the buffer with emacs, do I kill the process?

Tags: gnu-screen, emacs, r

I'm running some R code with an R session.

I begin by opening the shell, typing in `screen` to begin a screen session, and then `emacs -nw`

Let's say I begin R with `R` and then run some code, e.g. `> source("script.R")`

How do I simply exit this session and keep this R code running? If I'm using `screen` and I kill the buffer with `C-x k`, do I kill the session?

Comment: Are you asking about "killing screen" or "killing your R program" ?   If you're asking about your R program, then screen is irrelevant.

Comment: [Please do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Even if the question is on-topic on both, pick one.

Comment: @Gilles ok, I will do so---sorry!

Answer (score 3):

If you close emacs, the R process will be killed. To keep it running, detach your screen session without closing emacs. I think this is bound to  `C-a d` by default.

In your example, you start by opening `screen` in a terminal:

```
screen
```

Then start emacs, using `-nw` to run it in text-mode:

```
emacs -nw
```

If you have ESS installed, start R via `M-x R`. If you're just running it in a shell (why? use ESS!) do that instead.

Now start your analysis. For example:

```
for(i in 1:100){
  Sys.sleep(5)
  print(i)
}
```

Now detach the session with `C-a d`. You can now close your terminal, and even log off your computer - but don't turn it off! When you want to see how your job is doing, open another terminal, call screen with the `-r` flag:

```
screen -r
```

And you'll see your R session, inside Emacs, is still working away:

```
> Sys.sleep(4)
> for(i in 1:100){
+ Sys.sleep(5)
+ print(i)
+ }
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
```

As long as you leave emacs and R running, and detach (but don't close) screen, and don't turn your computer off, that's all you need.

Comment: How do you recommend allowing R to continue? I suppose you could continue to run emacs as a server: `emacs --nw --daemon`

Comment: I don't understand. All running processes in a screen session continue when you detach it. You don't need to do anything more.

Answer (score 2):

If that is the only window you have, killing *that* window will also kill `screen`.  As long as you have a window open, `screen` should still be running.  For instance, you might be running **`R`** in another window.

But usually when you kill a window, what's in it stops also, because `screen` sends it a signal:

> Kill current window.
>   If  there is an *exec* command running then it is killed. Otherwise the
>   process (shell) running in the window receives a **`HANGUP`** condition,  the
>   window  structure  is  removed  and  screen  (your display) switches to
>   another window.  When the  last  window  is  destroyed,  screen  exits.
>   After a kill screen switches to the previously displayed window.
>   Note:  Emacs  users  should  keep  this command in mind, when killing a
>   line.  It is recommended not to use **`"C-a"`** as the screen escape  key  or
>   to rebind kill to **`"C-a K"`**.

If you are running **`R`** in an Emacs buffer, then (having taken no provision for putting it into the background, and/or not using **`nohup`**) then killing the Emacs window would take **`R`** along with it.

You can of course detach from a screen session (that is different from *killing* a window): <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

But it helps to read the [manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)

Answer (score 2):

Screen is a terminal multiplexer then has a server/client model. When you start screen, it forks itself in the background to start the server and then the foreground client start communicating to it. What this does is allows it to keep running in the background no matter what happens to your client (whether it be killed, you lose connection if it's running over ssh or anything else).

To detach the screen client from the server by pressing <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd>. You can then use `screen -ls` to list all running screen sessions and `screen -r` to attach to the last one.

However, if you are running R inside emacs inside screen, then it is up to emacs when to close the R program, screen has no say in it.

Screen also allows you to split the window and have multiple windows. You can use this instead of launching the application with emacs to keep it running even when you exit emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running a shell in Emacs?  If so, you can use Unix job control to put the `R` script in the background: Once your `R` script is running, type `Ctrl-C Ctrl-Z` to return to the shell prompt.  This will suspend your script.  Then type `bg` to restart the job you just suspended in the background.  You can see that the job is running in the background using the shell command `jobs`.

Another way to accomplish what you want is by starting your `R` script in the background from the beginning.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208976/r-run-source-in-background) for doing it in `R`, or [this link](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/system/R-background.shtml) to do it directly from the command line.

Comment: Running a program in the background isn't the same as running it in a `screen` session. Screen sessions persist even after you log out, where background processes are killed on logout.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed OP wanted to stay in Emacs (my favorite pastime) as `C-x k` is an Emacs command -- I should have asked/waited for clarification.